# Why isn't the background of a margin same color as the page/element background?

Tags: html, css

I had to add a 20px margin and the color of that margin is white. This has never happened to me and I'm wondering why it isn't the same color as the page/element background.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the page it's on:

http://www.bolistylus.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<div id="page">` element has a background set to `White` (style.css line 325)

The element in question `#site-generator` has no parent background specified, so it uses the grand-parent element `#page`.

You can either change that styling on `#page` or add a background color to the `footer` element

Comment: I have already added the correct background color to ``site-generator``  ``#site-generator {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 border-top: 1px solid #17649a;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 2.2em;
 padding: 2.2em 0.5em;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}``

Comment: any space created by margin will not use that element's background color, the space created by margin will be colored from a parent element, in this case `footer`, set the `footer` background color to fix it.

Comment: margin creates space outside of the element, padding creates space within the element.

Comment: So weird, I added ``.footer {
 background: #f3f3f3;
}`` and it still is showing up white. The page is at http://www.bolistylus.com/shop/ if you want to take a gander. Thanks

Comment: ah, I think you want just `footer { background: #f3f3f3; }` (no period in the selector)

Comment: Beauty, worked like a charm!!1 Thanks a ton. Why only footer instead of .footer. Isn't footer a class?

Comment: your site is using the HTML5 `<footer>` element, if it was instead `<div class="footer">` then `.footer {}` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using PADDING instead of MARGIN.

**Padding** - *defines space between border and element content.*

**Margin** - *defines space between border and other outer elements.*

To learn more regarding the differences, please refer [here](http://www.digizol.com/2006/12/margin-vs-padding-css-properties.html).